# html5 minlength is not working in chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)

Tags: html, validation

My Chrome version is greater than 40, but still "minlength" attribute is not working.

```
 <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>    
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="{{$employee->profile->mobile}}" placeholder="Mobile" data-validation="number" data-validation-error-msg="The phone number must be 10 characters" maxlength="10" minlength="10">
```

Answer (score 3):

Minlength works when the value is typed into the input by a user. If it's hardcoded in the source or set programmatically using JavaScript (for example), minlength won't be enforced.

Where is `{{$employee->profile->mobile}}` coming from? The data should be modified to meet the constraints before it's set.

Comment: Thanks it worked.Initially i was using jquery for user to enter only number type and jquery form validator, so when i removed jquery code it worked.